# HTTPS file upload and email

Tags: php, https, file-get-contents, multipartform-data

I currently have a site in php that uses http socket. So for security purposes we desided to change and force the site to HTTPS , we made changes to . httaccass adding:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

this forces the site to https and all seems fine, but then my problem is that our current pages that does file uploading and file uploading and sending as an email is not working anymore.

The file upload page code:

```
            $strHeader .= "From: My site <".$from.">\n";
            $strHeader .= "To: $t\n"; //was $to for a batch send
            $strHeader .= $cc;
            $strHeader .= $bcc;
            $strHeader .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
            $strHeader .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$strSid."\"\n\n";
            $strHeader .= "Subject: $subject\n";
            $strHeader .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

            $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
            $strHeader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
            $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n";
            $strHeader .= $message."\n\n";

$strFilesName = $_FILES["fileAttach2"]["name"];
                            $strContent = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES["fileAttach2"]["tmp_name"]))); 
                            $strHeader .= "--".$strSid."\n";
                            $strHeader .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n"; 
                            $strHeader .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
                            $strHeader .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$strFilesName."\"\n\n";
$strHeader .= $strContent."\n\n";
```

This worked fine with http , but what should i do to enable this in https? and then also for normal upload of files to directories and some scripts that generate files like pdf?

Comment: File upload is a PUT request. URL redirects will generally have the browser use GET on the page redirected to, not PUT. Remove the rewrite, and fix your form that does the upload to have https:// in its action.

Comment: @Guntram Blohm `File upload is a PUT request` - you sure? More in any way?

Comment: See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1867.txt if you want the details, but you can't do a file upload with GET.

Comment: Ok the upload works now by changing the request to https:// ..Thanx